# Radio Button Formatting in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want to use this snippet from [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/product-chooser-selector) in one of my CakePHP views but I'm having trouble converting the raw HTML code into Cake's FormHelper method..

I'm not sure how to even get started given that each radio button will have a slightly different bit of code for the image source URLs.. any advice?

My working code is completely useless, but by stating:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Product Choice', $attributes); ?>
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="row form-group product-chooser">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="product-chooser-item selected">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <span class="title">Level 1</span>
                        <span class="description">Dummy Text</span>
                        <input type="radio" name="ProductChoice" value="1" checked="checked">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="product-chooser-item">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <span class="title">Level 2 </span>
                        <span class="description">Dummy Text</span>
                        <input type="radio" name="ProductChoice" value="2>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

However, not sure how to construct the $attributes array..

Comment: If you are using version above 2.0, use this:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: Yeah I have been following that but I'm not sure how to iterate over the different options with the different image source paths..

Comment: Please add the code you're using, the exact markup you need to achieve (and your current result) to the question.

Comment: Use Html Helper for images
: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ankit, but I've read through the documentation and it's not just one single part. I'm confused as to construct the state that would replicate the raw HTML code described above..